# PHP Not passing variables through to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am passing through The continent to the `PHP` file from a `js` file. Basically I need to insert the data to the database (put the continent in) and get the `ID` of it, but no matter what I do, it returns either an `empty string` or a `500 Internal Service Error`.

Here is the `PHP Code`:

```
$continent = $_POST['continent'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO location_continent (`name`) VALUES ('". $continent ."')";

if(!$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT id FROM location_continent WHERE `name` = '". $continent ."'";
$result2 = $con->query($sql);
if(!$result2){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');
}
return $result2->num_rows;
```

Here is the `JS Code`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'process.php?section=continent',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'continent='+key,
        success: function(res) {
            continentid = res;
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
```

The `Key` that is passed through would be something like `Africa`.

I have tried the following in the `php file`:

```
return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
return $result;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

I have struggled for around 2 hours now. I cannot seem to find the error.

**Note**
Please note that the information is being inserted to the database just fine, just that I cannot get the ID.

Comment: check console what is your post url?

Comment: Did you set any header in PHP? Consider doing `exit()` at the end of PHP code.

Comment: post URL is: `process.php?section=continent`

Comment: make your post url to be accessed directly, it seems like ajax is not able to post the data on your mentioned url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ajax you need to print/echo output for return data rather return statement so try to replace

```
return $result2->num_rows;
```

to

```
echo $result2->num_rows;
```

also you can send your query string like:-

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'section':'continent','continent':key},
        success: function(res) {
            continentid = res;
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
```

Then check your post data by echo if correct something wrong with query executing can't find `$con` and `$db` defined on posted code

Answer (score 0):

You are returning but you are not in a function, so try echoing instead (`echo mysqli_insert_id($conn);`)